# Sql 2000 floats not displaying decimal when performing division

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm performing a percentage calculation, but it is displaying whole numbers.  I tried to convert from int to float, but its still displaying as integer.  How can I fix it to display decimal.

The calculation I'm using is 100.0 * (1.0 + (floatA / (floatA + floatB)))

this is where floatA = 1, floatB = 1   so I should see a value of 50.0 % instead I'm seeing a value of 100.

I'm trying to get the thing to use decimals.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How/Where are you converting from int to float?

Comment: floatA is just a count... ie.. count(tblA.Col1) and floatB is the same thing but for tblB, since they are part of count function I am having trouble performing a calcualtion based on the counts and getting a result other than whole number b/c it rounds off to the nearest whole number and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The counts i mentioned above are part of a group by expression where they aggregate the number of times it appeared in the group by expression. I think that has something to do with who it doesn't create a decimal number and sticks with whole number.  I need to turn off this feature if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `floatA` and `floatB` are values returned by `COUNT` then they will be integer.

You need to cast at least one of the operands involved in the division to `float`/`decimal` to avoid integer division in that part of the expression.

```
100.0 * (1.0 + (floatA / (floatA + CAST(floatB as float))))
```

Comment: Thanks i was starting to pull my hair out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using floatA = 1 and floatB = 1, then pencil-and-paper arithmetic should give you 150. But those are integers, not floats.

But on most SQL platforms, this statement

```
select 1 / (1 + 1)
```

will return zero.

[Integer division truncates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276874%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

This

```
select 100.0 * (1.0 + (1.0/ (1.0 + 1.0)))
```

should give you 150.

Answer (score 1):

By simply casting one of your values to a float type solves the problem.

```
select (12345/6789)
```

the example above will return 1 i.e. the result got truncated to integer

```
select (cast(12345 as float)/ cast(6789 as float))
select (12354/ cast(6789 as float))
```

these examples will return 1.81838267786125

Comment: I think you only need to cast one number float, but its probably better to cast or convert all to float or use a declaration that is defined as float. thx